# Proving a triangle isosceles using Thales Theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: triangle diagram]

Given that:

1. [BM) is the bisector of the angle ABC.
2. (BM) and (AN) are parallel straight lines.

I am trying to prove that the triangle ANB is an isosceles triangle with a main vertex B using Thales Theorem.

Here's what I have done:

Since BM and AN are parallel then by using Thales Theorem:
$MA/MC = NB/BC = BM/AN$

I don't know where to go from here.. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Look for the alternate interior angles and corresponding angles in the figure.

Comment: If you *have* to use Thales' Theorem, you also need to apply the interior angle bisector theorem and combine the results.

Comment: Can u give me an answer with a more detailed explanation  that will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the alternate interior angles and corresponding angles in the figure: $\measuredangle MBA=\measuredangle BAN$ and $\measuredangle CBM=\measuredangle BNA$, so the triangle is isosceles.

---

If you insist to use Thales':

$$AM/CM = BN/BC$$

From interior angle bisector theorem:

$$AM/CM=AB/BC$$

Combining the two:

$$BN/BC=AB/BC \implies AB=BN$$

Comment: Thankssssssssss, I don't know the interior bisector Theorem but I'll check it now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not using Thales's intercept theorem, but:

$AN \parallel BM$, so from $AB$ crossing $\color{#092}{\angle NAB} = \color{#02E}{\angle ABM}$ and from $CN$ crossing $\color{#092}{\angle ANB} = \color{#02E}{\angle MBC}$.

Since $BM$ bisects $\angle ABC$, $\color{#02E}{\angle ABM =  \angle MBC}$ so $\color{#092}{\angle NAB =\angle ANB }$, giving $\triangle BAN$ isosceles.